# Combine frequency tables into a single data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I have a list in which each list item is a word frequency table derived from using "table()" on a different sample text.  Each table is, therefore, a different length.  I want to now convert the list into a single data frame in which each column is a word each row is a sample text.  Here is a dummy example of my data:

```
t1<-table(strsplit(tolower("this is a test in the event of a real word file you would see many more words here"), "\\W"))

t2<-table(strsplit(tolower("Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal"), "\\W"))

t3<-table(strsplit(tolower("Ask not what your country can do for you - ask what you can do for your country"), "\\W"))

myList <- list(t1, t2, t3)
```

so, one gets this sort of structure:

```
> class(myList[[3]])
[1] "table"

> myList[[3]]

        ask     can country      do     for     not    what     you    your 
  2       2       2       2       2       2       1       2       2       2
```

I now need to convert this list (myList) into a single data frame.  I thought I could do this with plyr, along the lines of what is done here (http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/01/23/r-combining-vectors-or-data-frames-of-unequal-length-into-one-data-frame/), e.g.

```
library(plyr)
l <- myList
do.call(rbind.fill, l)
```

But it seems that my "table" objects do not play nice.  I tried converting them to dfs and also to vectors, but none of that worked quite right.

Comment: oh wait, in my answer I assumed you wanted a separate data.frame column for each table.. Were you after a different format than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
freqs.list <- mapply(data.frame,Words=seq_along(myList),myList,SIMPLIFY=FALSE,MoreArgs=list(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
freqs.df <- do.call(rbind,freqs.list)
res <- reshape(freqs.df,timevar="Words",idvar="Var1",direction="wide")
head(res)
```

Answer (score 7):

**1. zoo**. The zoo package has a multiway merge function which can do this compactly.  The `lapply` converts each component of `myList` to a zoo object and then we simply merge them all:

```
# optionally add nice names to the list
names(myList) <- paste("t", seq_along(myList), sep = "")

library(zoo)
fz <- function(x)with(as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), zoo(Freq, Var1)))
out <- do.call(merge, lapply(myList, fz))
```

The above returns a multivariate zoo series in which the "times" are `"a"`, `"ago"`, etc. but if a data frame result were desired then its just a matter of `as.data.frame(out)`.

**2. Reduce**.   Here is a second solution. It uses `Reduce` in the core of R.

```
merge1 <- function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 1, all = TRUE)
out <- Reduce(merge1, lapply(myList, as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

# optionally add nice names
colnames(out)[-1] <- paste("t", seq_along(myList), sep = "")
```

**3. xtabs**.  This one adds names to the list and then extracts the frequencies, names and groups as one long vector each putting them back together using `xtabs`:

```
names(myList) <- paste("t", seq_along(myList))

xtabs(Freq ~ Names + Group, data.frame(
    Freq = unlist(lapply(myList, unname)),
    Names = unlist(lapply(myList, names)),
    Group = rep(names(myList), sapply(myList, length))
))
```

**Benchmark**

Benchmarking some of the solutions using the rbenchmark package we get the following which indicates that the zoo solution is the fastest on the sample data and is arguably the simplest as well.

```
> t1<-table(strsplit(tolower("this is a test in the event of a real word file you would see many more words here"), "\\W"))
> t2<-table(strsplit(tolower("Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal"), "\\W"))
> t3<-table(strsplit(tolower("Ask not what your country can do for you - ask what you can do for your country"), "\\W"))
> myList <- list(t1, t2, t3)
> 
> library(rbenchmark)
> library(zoo)
> names(myList) <- paste("t", seq_along(myList), sep = "")
> 
> benchmark(xtabs = {
+ names(myList) <- paste("t", seq_along(myList))
+ xtabs(Freq ~ Names + Group, data.frame(
+ Freq = unlist(lapply(myList, unname)),
+ Names = unlist(lapply(myList, names)),
+ Group = rep(names(myList), sapply(myList, length))
+ ))
+ },
+ zoo = {
+ fz <- function(x) with(as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), zoo(Freq, Var1))
+ do.call(merge, lapply(myList, fz))
+ },
+ Reduce = {
+ merge1 <- function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 1, all = TRUE)
+ Reduce(merge1, lapply(myList, as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
+ },
+ reshape = {
+ freqs.list <- mapply(data.frame,Words=seq_along(myList),myList,SIMPLIFY=FALSE,MoreArgs=list(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
+ freqs.df <- do.call(rbind,freqs.list)
+ reshape(freqs.df,timevar="Words",idvar="Var1",direction="wide")
+ }, replications = 10, order = "relative", columns = c("test", "replications", "relative"))
     test replications relative
2     zoo           10 1.000000
4 reshape           10 1.090909
1   xtabs           10 1.272727
3  Reduce           10 1.272727
```

ADDED: second solution.

ADDED: third solution.

ADDED: benchmark.

Comment: Thanks G. but when I run your code example, I get an error:Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

Answer (score 1):

Here is an inelegant way that gets the job done. I'm sure there's a 1-liner out there just for this, but I dunno where either:

```
    myList <- list(t1=t1, t2=t2, t3=t3)
    myList <- lapply(myList,as.data.frame,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    Words <- unique(unlist(lapply(myList,function(x) x[,1])))
    DFmerge <- data.frame(Words=Words)
    for (i in 1:3){
        DFmerge <- merge(DFmerge,myList[[i]],by.x="Words",by.y="Var1",all.x=TRUE)
    }
    colnames(DFmerge) <- c("Words","t1","t2","t3")
```

And looking around a bit more, here's another way that gives output more similar to that in the linked blog post: [Edit: works now]

```
    myList <- list(t1=t1, t2=t2, t3=t3)
    myList <- lapply(myList,function(x) {
        A <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(x),nrow=1))
        colnames(A) <- names(x)
        A[,colnames(A) != ""]
        }
    )   
    do.call(rbind.fill,myList)
```

Also ugly, so maybe a better answer will still come along.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was hoping to avoid the for loop, but this does seem to get the job done.  I can then transpose the df and do a little pruning so that words are column names. . . still, seems to me there ought to be a plyr based solution. . . .

Comment: @litlogger the second method, still ugly, now works and avoids a for loop

Comment: and I should mention, the punctuation marks, e.g. `"-"` turn into `""` in `names(x)`, and this caused errors for `rbind.fill()`. I tossed them out in the anonymous `lapply` function. Just FYI, in case that wasn't desired

Comment: Tim, good catch on the punctuation.  I was getting errors in my own testing, and I see now that the punctuation marks were the cause.  Contrary to my intuition, it also appears that your first, looping, solution is more efficient than the plyr solution, at least when I apply this to my real data set which has about 55,000 unique words!

Comment: @litlogger fancy that! Note in the loopy version that all punctuation marks are grouped into a single row under `""`