# Producing a frequency table dataframe from a folder of txt files

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to basically have a frequency table from a column in individual text files from a folder into a single nice dataframe.

I have a folder with 1000 files. Each of the 1000 text files is tab-del UTF-8 (or so they say, encoding has been an issue), with 61 columns and a varying number of rows from 35-500.

In each file, column 43 is a year. My desired end state would be a dataframe with a column for each year that appears in the dataset at all, a row for each of the 1000 files, and the total of times that year appears in that file in each cell (in other words, the number of times each year appears in column 43)

I have this function:

```
  findCY<-function(savedfile){
  text <- read.delim(savedfile, header=FALSE, sep="\t",colClasses=mycolClasses, quote="", na.strings="", encoding="UTF-8-BOM")
  cyvec<- as.numeric(text$V43[2:(length(text$V43))])
  cyvec<- sort(cyvec, decreasing=FALSE)
  labelcyvec<-c(savedfile,cyvec)
  return(labelcyvec)
}
```

Where

```
mycolClasses<-c("character", rep("NULL",29),"character",rep("NULL",11),"character",rep("NULL",18))
```

And a character vector with the filenames - called filenames. I tried to call like so:

```
test<- ldply(filenames[600:605], findCY)
```

And then I melt and recast and got a beautiful data.frame:

```
test.melt<-melt(test,id.vars="V1")
test.cast<-dcast(test.melt, V1~value, fun.aggregate=length)
```

It works beautifully with rows 600-605 but when I try the whole thing, or even any other subset I get the following error from the ldply step:

> Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id,
>   id_as_factor) :    Results do not have equal lengths

I know that the individual files do not all have the same year coverage or the same number of rows and I think this may be the problem.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: How about using `lapply` instead of `ldply`? Still error?

Comment: I can use lapply to get a list. I'm looking at that now.I also tried some things from here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250344/combine-frequency-tables-into-a-single-data-frame?rq=1 with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Changing the function to output a list of data frames and using lapply does work, then melt is not required, just cast:

```
findCY<-function(savedfile){
  text <- read.delim(savedfile, header=FALSE, sep="\t",colClasses=mycolClasses, quote="", na.strings="", encoding="UTF-8-BOM")
  cyvec<- as.numeric(text$V43[2:(length(text$V43))])
  cyvec<- sort(cyvec, decreasing=FALSE)
  labelcyvec<-data.frame(savedfile,cyvec)
  print(c(savedfile,"ok"))
  return(labelcyvec)
}

CYall<- ldply(filenames, findCY)
CYall.cast<- dcast(CYall, savedfile~cyvec, fun.aggregate=length)
```

Now I'm thoroughly confused because apparently I did use ldply - but it worked!